# Count where query in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I am having a issue here that I am not solving.
I am trying to make a query in Laravel where I need to count how many offers does a business has, to show Business id, Total Offers for a Business and Business Name.

```
$business_offers = DB::table('offers')
        ->join('businesses', 'offers.id_business', '=', 'businesses.id')
        ->select(['businesses.id', 'businesses.name', DB::raw('count(offers.id) as total_offers')])
        ->orderby('total_offers', 'DESC')
        ->get();
```

but it is not working in this way. I have also done the query in mysql but can't integrate it in Laravel.

```
SELECT bu.id,(SELECT count(of.id) from offers of where of.id_business = bu.id )
 as total_offers, bu.`name` from businesses bu ORDER BY total_offers DESC
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading it literally something like the following might work:

```
$business_offers = DB::table('businesses bu')
    ->select(['bu.id', DB::raw("(SELECT count(of.id) from offers of where of.id_business = bu.id )") ,'bu.name'])
    ->orderBy('total_offers', 'DESC')
    ->get();
```

If you want it a bit more efficient (maybe):

```
$business_offers = DB::table('offers')
    ->join('businesses', 'offers.id_business', '=', 'businesses.id')
    ->select(['businesses.id', DB::raw("COUNT(1) as total_offers"),'businesses.name'])
    ->groupBy("businesses.id","businesses.name")
    ->orderBy('total_offers', 'DESC')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have models and relations set up it should be as easy as:

```
$businesses = Business::withCount(['offers'])->get;

foreach ($businesses as $business) {
    echo $business->offers_count;
}
```

From the Laravel [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships):

> If you want to count the number of results from a relationship without
>   actually loading them you may use the withCount method, which will
>   place a {relation}_count column on your resulting models.

All you need in your Business model is:

```
class Business extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the offers for the business.
     */
    public function offers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Offer');
    }
}
```

and in the Offer model:

```
class Offer extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the business for the current offer.
     */
    public function business()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Business', 'business_id');

    }
}
```

Comment: no the relations are not set, thats why I need to do it as the form I have posted in the question.

Comment: I've edited my reply with the basics of the relationships. I would highly recommend reading the documentation linked to in my answer.

Comment: I appreciate your answer a lot, but I need it the way i have post it mate, because the project is live and cant do such big changes right now.

Comment: That is the answer, it is a collection of businesses with their name, id, and a count of offers.

Comment: I understand that it is the best way to do it, I thanks you a lot for your time and that you stopped by, but I repeat it again I need it in the query form. Thank you!